# What happens if we use "decltype(auto) f()" as a function declaration with "decltype(f()) result" in the definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This is really a C++14 question.  And it's more theoretical than practical.

Sometimes you build a function's result in piecemeal:

```
int f( int x, int y )
{
    int  a;
    //...
    return a;
}
```

but if you change the return type, you have to change the type of "a" too.  I get around this with a special declaration:

```
int f( int x, int y )
{
    decltype( f(x,y) )  a;
    //...
    return a;
}
```

(For the newbies: what is the pitfall if a function parameter uses an r-value reference?  Hint: we need `std::forward` to fix it.)  A question randomly popped into my head: what if I use the new C++14 feature of "`decltype( auto )`" as the return type?!  Will we get a recursive black hole?  Or an error that it's not allowed?  Would adding an initializer to "a" make everything all-right?

Comment: [dcl.spec.auto]/11 "If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression,
the program is ill-formed.  Once a return statement has been seen in a function, however, the return type
deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other return statements."

Comment: eurgh - that `decltype( f(x,y) )` is horrible - making that unnecessary is the best rationale I've seen for auto return type deduction!

Comment: @DyP, so I could have a quick-and-dirty `if` & `return` block at the beginning of the function, then use the `decltype(f(X))` construct afterwards (for the rest of the function)?

Comment: @CTMacUser Yes, I think so. [Live example, clang++3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ca3dbea502fb950)

Comment: @DyP, could you put your work in the form of a regular answer so I can close this and give you points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A question randomly popped into my head: what if I use the new C++14
>   feature of "decltype( auto )" as the return type?!

The example the OP is referring to is:

```
auto f( int x, int y ) // using C++1y's return type deduction
{
    decltype( f(x,y) )  a;
    //...
    return a;
}
```

> Will we get a recursive black hole? Or an error that it's not allowed?

It's not allowed [dcl.spec.auto]/11:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed
>   to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.
>   Once a return statement has been seen in a function, however, the
>   return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the
>   function, including in other return statements.

---

> Would adding an initializer to `a` make everything all-right?

Ex.

```
decltype( f(x,y) )  a = 42;
```

No; the use of `decltype` requires determining the return type of `f`. However, the following is possible:

```
auto a = 42;
```

From a comment:

> so I could have a quick-and-dirty `if` & `return` block at the beginning of the function, then use the `decltype(f(X))` construct afterwards (for the rest of the function)?

Yes, e.g.

```
auto f( int x, int y ) // using C++1y's return type deduction
{
    if(false) return int();

    decltype( f(x,y) )  a;
    //...
    return a;
}
```

However, I'd prefer either:

```
auto f( int x, int y ) // using C++1y's return type deduction
{
    int a; // specifying the return type of `f` here
    //...
    return a;
}
```

or

```
auto f( int x, int y ) // using C++1y's return type deduction
{
    auto a = 42; // specifying the return type of `f` via the initializer
    //...
    return a;
}
```